# How can I run the Alloy model checker API in Eclipse?

Tags: java, import, importerror, alloy

I am having trouble importing Alloy libraries to use the API in Eclipse. This is the code I am trying to run: http://alloytools.org/documentation/code/ExampleUsingTheAPI.java.html

The problem is that I am doing something wrong importing the libraries. So this is what I did:

1. Create a new Java Project (JRE: jdk1.8.0_172) in Eclipse
2. Right Click in the project > Import > Archive File > select the .jar file `org.alloytools.alloy.dist.jar` downloaded from https://alloytools.org/download.html
3. All folders and files are added as in the next picture below.
4. Create new file in scr folder: ExampleUsingTheAPI.java, with the code from http://alloytools.org/documentation/code/ExampleUsingTheAPI.java.html

[image]

**The errors displayed are:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar, right click on your project, select configure build path, click on libraries and add external jar, select your Alloy api and click apply and ok.
If i'm not wrong it should work, i used to do the same when using eclipse.